# How can I get Uri of a media file in android?

Tags: android, uri, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I want to play a video with `MediaPlayer` in android, code is something like this:

`MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this.getContext, mUri, mHeaders)`

I have a local file: `/storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4`, how can I get the `mUri` of this file?

In fact, `android.net.Uri` have a method `fromFile(File file)`, it returns a Uri like this: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4`. But this does work in `setDataSource()` method.

**UPDATED:**
I don't want to misleading someone in this problem.

**In fact, `Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4")` and `Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4")` should be ok in my situation. But it is just my mp4 file's problem!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your file:/... to file:/// and it will work

```
Uri.parse(uri.toString().replace("file:/", "file:///"));
```

or simply if you have a file try

```
Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(myFile)));
```

Actually the thing is that the media player requires [MRL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_resource_locator) followed by your path to file

**EDIT**

I have answered a question on how to initialise MediaPlayer using Uri [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184816/2319390)

Use the above MRL and initialise your player as suggested and enjoy your video :)

**UPDATE:**

I thought I should share part of my implementation so that it may help you out:

**1st**
Add below line to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**2nd**

Make your activity look like

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        String stringPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/Lesson%201/30%20-%20Create%20Some%20Fake%20Data.mp4";
        stringPath = android.net.Uri.parse("file://" + stringPath).getPath();

        try {

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(stringPath);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and for testing your xml can be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="169dp"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: :) I am currently building a Music/Video Player application and above MRL works for sure

Comment: I am working on a project like yours, but I am working in android TV. What I said is `Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(myFile)));` in my project.

Comment: actually the media player doesn't like uri's like file:/storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4, instead feed it with uri like file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4 , this file:// follwed by /storage... is called MRL

Comment: I have seen your answer, it seems that you play a video from Internet but what I want to play is a local video. I have tried `Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4")` and `Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4")`, they can not play the video successfuly either.

Comment: I have updated my answer :) it is working fine.. tell me anything else you require

Comment: Finally, I find the problem. The problem is my mp4 file. After I change another mp4 file, it works fine!`/storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4` is ok!

Comment: Although I solve my problem. But do you know why two mp4 file, one is ok while the other is not ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
String filePath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4"
filePath.replace("file:///", "/"));

MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(filePath));
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: As I metion`Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4")` can not work. Of course I have tried `Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4")` too, it cannot work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm offering another answer to the original question, which may not be applicable to the specific problem as described by @roger later on. I have found that there is no need to further process/parse the media file path. Just use it directly. For example, I have a locally-stored media file on my Samsung Galaxy phone:  "/storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over_the_Horizon.mp3"
. The following simple code works for playing the file:

```
String url = "/storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over_the_Horizon.mp3";
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```

(I have omitted try-catch blocks and other non-basic code). If SecurityException or IOException is issued while running the code, most likely a user permission needs to be added at the right place inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <application
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```